# Convert Kafka connect Struct to POJO

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm working on component that capture data change (CDC) from a database, apply some business logic on data then send them to a new topic which is an azure event hub topic.

My stack includes :

- Camel pipelines
- Debezium Embedded (for CDC)

This [article](https://debezium.io/blog/2020/02/19/debezium-camel-integration/) from debezium was the basis I started working on. A Converter is used to transform the Struct to a POJO.

```
  @Converter
  public static class Converters {

    @Converter
    public static Question questionFromStruct(Struct struct) {                   
      return new Question(struct.getInt64("id"), struct.getString("text"),
          struct.getString("email"));
    }

    @Converter
    public static Answer answerFromStruct(Struct struct) {                       
      return new Answer(struct.getInt64("id"), struct.getString("text"),
          struct.getString("email"), struct.getInt64("question_id"));
    }
  }
```

In my case the POJO I'm handling is an Avro generated one. Also it includes more than 20 attributes I don't want to set manually.

I thought about mappers such as MapStruct or Dozer. But the don't handle this kind of mapping.

Any insights on how to handle `struct` with more automation?

Answer (score 1):

As written in the Debezium Engine docs

> Internally, the engine uses the appropriate Kafka Connect converter implementation to which the conversion is delegated

This means, you need to reverse the Converter methods, then use a Kafka Deserializer class to get data back to a POJO that would have been originally produced.

---

Assuming you used Confluent's AvroConverter, then you should be able to use [`AvroConverter#fromConnectData`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/7.0.1-post/avro-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroConverter.java#L83) to return a `byte[]` as the key/value. You will first need the Connect `Schema` instance for your `Struct`, though.

From that, you can pass the bytes to [`KafkaAvroDeserializer#deserialize`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/7.0.1-post/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaAvroDeserializer.java#L54) and cast the response to your generated class.

---

Alternatively, the proper way to transform data within Debezium/Kafka Connect is to use Simple-Message-Transforms and stay within the Struct/Schema APIs.

Comment: I'm actually using debezium embedeed, if you take a look at the debezium article I posted.  Besides the struct are part of pipeline and are triggered by debezium. The method you pointed me out to need a topic to be given isn't it.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what framework you're using. The "topic name" is only to perform a subject-name lookup in the Schema Registry, not actually do anything with a Kafka client

Comment: I might be wrong but it obliges me to have a schema registry and a kafka connector two things I don't want to have. Is the any other way for the conversion ?

Comment: Debezium is a Kafka Connector, embedded or not. I made assumptions about how you are producing data. If you are not using Confluent `AvroConverter`, then Debezium/Camel do not have built-in Avro functions that I am aware of, so how does that data get created before Structs are built?

Comment: It is built out of the box with camel component for debezium that serves me afterward Struct that I want to retransform. It is basically an object mapping that I want to do but Struct object is difficult to handle

Comment: Okay, I see [Avro is an output format](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/development/engine.html#engine-output-message-formats). But doesn't really document more than that. In any case, the only way to do what you're asking is via the `Converter` interface and the `fromConnectData` method, like I said. For example, if you used JSON [it would be the same](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonConverter.java#L299).

Comment: And looking into the source code, the Confluent Converter is used, which requires a Schema Registry (which could be embedded into the Engine, I guess) - https://github.com/debezium/debezium/commit/c06707f4c50fa0e17675651dc411ed933a33e732#diff-5eaeb1dbce7c9ef50c430deffff0d5f957012da072b0ba880460738d99a9e1c2R155